# In Magento module configuration, would show_in_default=0 be unusual?

Tags: magento

I just grepped through all the sytem.xml files for show_in_default having a value of 0, and it came back with very little. An export button in the Shipping module was about it. Why is it so unusual? I am thinking of having a configuration setting that I let the user set once, and then once it has been set once, they cannot change it. Having the Default/Website/Store scope stuff makes that awkward, and so I was thinking of only showing the setting at the Website scope. Is that a valid thing to do?

Answer (score 0):

yes it is valid and you can define your scope as you like. But is it wise?